# Why is the button in an offset position

Tags: .net, vb.net, coordinates, offset

Here is the code:

```
Dim nBtn As New Button
    PictureBox1.Controls.Add(nBtn)
    nBtn.Text = "Click Me"
    nBtn.Location = Cursor.Position ' or mouseposition = same result
```

[image]

that's how it looks.. its about 2 inches away from where I originally clicked it. My code doesn't even offset its location, so how is this happening?
That is a picture box inside the right side of `SplitContainer`.

Comment: Can you create a short but *complete* program to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Control.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) refers to the location *relative to the control's container* (or rather, its top-left point).

[`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and [`Control.MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) refer to a location *relative to the top-left corner of the screen*.

So if your control's container happens to be at the top-left of the screen, your code will work. Otherwise, it will be offset as you've seen. You should see whether the [`Control.PointToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Control.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods help you; the documentation isn't entirely clear to me, but they *may* be exactly what you need. For example:

```
nBtn.Location = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
```